# Find two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an element of $B$ and $A \subseteq B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an element of $B$ and $A \subseteq B$.

Would $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3\}$ work?

Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to say with "denotes"? Is equal to? If so, you are looking for a set $A\in B=A$, which is not permitted. At any rate, $\{1,2,3\}$ is not an element of $\{1,2,3\}$

Comment: sorry i meant A is the subset of B

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. The first comment still stands: $\{1,2,3\}$ is not an element of itself. It is certainly a subset of itself, though.

Comment: So what would be the right answer in this case?

Comment: There is no *the* right answer for this question. There are many right answers. You can even adapt your first attempt into a correct answer. Don't just give up after you try one thing!

Answer (score 6):

For your revised question: $$\text{Let }\;A = \{1, 2, 3\}, \quad B = \{1, 2, 3, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$$

$$A = \{1, 2, 3\} \in \{1, 2, 3, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$$
 $$A = \{1, 2, 3\} \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$$

Answer (score 4):

$A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{\emptyset\}$

Answer (score 4):

No, they can't be equal, because (under the normal axioms for sets) a set cannot belong to itself.

But if you think to $A=\emptyset$, …